# How to use IHTTPAsyncHandler?

Tags: asp.net, ihttpasynchandler

Imagine I have some code to read from the start to end of a file like so:

```
while(sw.readline != null)
{

}
```

I want this to be fully asynchronous. When deriving from IHTTPAsyncHandler, where would this code go and where would would the code to get the content of each line go?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I recently added some asynchronous processes to my ASP.NET pages in order to allow some long-running processes to take place while the user waited for the results. I found the IHTTPAsyncHandler quite inadequate. All it does is allow you to spin off a new thread while the page begins processing. You still have to make your own thread and create a AsyncRequestResult.

Instead I ended up just using a normal thread in my codebehind instead, much more succinct:

```
using System;
using System.Web;
using System.Threading;

namespace Temp {
    public partial class thread : System.Web.UI.Page {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
            Thread thread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(myAsyncProcess));
            thread.Start();
        }

        private void myAsyncProcess() {
            // Long running process
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't you be clueless as to when that function was finished?

Comment: Yes, usually I'd use this to just call a long running process and forget about it. But if I needed to know when it was done, or if it even finished, the end of the process can update a status in a database. If the web page you are on needs to know when it is done, say a progress bar followed by a "Completed!" message, you can have myAsyncProcess update a Session object periodically along the way. Then use a client-side timer (ASP.NET AJAX Timer, for example) to call a function on the server to check the Session status.

Comment: I used the your code but an exception is thrown: `Synchronous execution of an asynchronous task is not allowed`

Comment: What are you doing inside you task? Never seen that error before. Just to test, I created a new page and project, and it compiled then executed without errors. (See the updated answer for source code.)